# Close reason for not specific enough questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, close-reasons

I had to mark [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015265/cryptlib-encryption-library-for-c) with a close reason of 'not a real question', but of course that isn't quite true.  I think we need a close reason of

> not specific enough of a question

or maybe

> too broad of a question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's difficult to tell what is being
>   asked here. This question is ambiguous
>   and vague, and cannot be answered in
>   its current form.

Doesn't the description of "Not a real question" already cover what you're asking for? Maybe it should just be changed to "Not an answerable question".

UPDATE: The NARQ close reason has since been expanded to include the characteristics "incomplete" and "overly broad".

Comment: That's a good alternative.

Comment: "Not an answerable question" somewhat overlaps with "subjective and argumentative".