# When to downvote, when to close vote, when to do both?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvotes versus close votes on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33286/downvotes-versus-close-votes-on-questions)

I know, we have lots of posts here on this subject. I would, nonetheless, find it helpful to see what the management and other experienced folks think of the specific comparison between downvoting and close-voting a question.

One paradigm might be this:

- If the post is a poorly written non-question, both.
- If the post is reasonably clear and readable, but off-topic, just close.
- If the post is reasonably clear and readable, but subjective/argumentative, just close.
- Duplicate, just close.

etc.

However, when I see a user with a moderate amount of rep repeatedly posting off-topic or soap-boxed opinion, however grammatical, I feel an itch to downvote, so as to deliver some sort of feedback that might change behavior. I know, this is not consistent with 'just rate the content', but there you have it.

Comment: May be related with your own post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33286/downvotes-versus-close-votes-on-questions - and this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38687/questions-with-incomplete-information-downvote-or-close

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automatic

Comment: Eh, Rosinante, would help if you could add what you have/haven't learned from your previous question on the subject. FWIW, I think you need to become more comfortable down-voting bad content when you see it *regardless* of whether or not it's part of a larger pattern by that user.

Answer (score 2):

> However, when I see a user with a
>   moderate amount of rep repeatedly
>   posting off-topic or soap-boxed
>   opinion, however grammatical, I feel
>   an itch to downvote, so as to deliver
>   some sort of feedback that might
>   change behavior.

I don't have a problem with using downvotes this way.  It is useful (and good Stackiquette) to leave a comment explaining why.